# is it right expression?

Tags: expressions, british-english

during Notting hill movie script.

```
 Anna : it was nice to meet you 
 William : and you
```

I do not understand the meaning behind the expression 'and you' 
is it right expression? 
or it does use  only in  England

Answer (score 2):

It is a correctly used expression. It is basically a shortened form of the expression, "and the same to you." It's probably more common in Great Britain than in the USA, but is not uncommon in either place.

Comment: but when someone said 'it was nice to meet you' usually people said 'me too' but how "and the same to you"  is same meaning as 'me too'?

Comment: They're not exactly the same. The "me too" answer normally follows a first-person statement, such as "I enjoyed meeting you." In this case, a reply of "me too," would be like saying, "I enjoyed meeting you too." The final resulting meaning of the exchange is the same. It's just a different way of saying it depending on whether the statement is in first-person (me, I), or second person (you).

Answer (score 1):

As Mrssbolton suggests, this is a very common expression in the U.K.

The 'and' is a way of duplicating what has been said to you and repeating it back to the speaker. So:

Anna: It was nice to meet you.

William: And (it was nice to meet) you.

or, another example:

Robert: You should have done things differently.

Jane: And you (should have done things differently).

HTH